# How to display Japanese characters on a php page?

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding

I'm trying to display Japanese characters on a PHP page.  No loading from the database, just stored in a language file and echo'ed out.

I'm running into a weird scenario.  I have the page properly setup with UTF-8 and I test a sample page on my local WAMP server and it works.

The moment I tested it out our development and production servers the characters don't display properly.

This leads me to believe then that it's a setting in php.ini.  But I haven't found much information about this so I'm not really sure if this is the issue.

Is there something fundamental I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you've stated that it is working in your development environment and not in your live, you might want to check Apache's [AddDefaultCharset](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#AddDefaultCharset) and set this to UTF-8, if it's not already.

I tend to make sure the following steps are checked

1. PHP Header is sent in UTF-8
2. Meta tag is set to UTF-8 (Content-Type)
3. Storage is set to UTF-8
4. Server output is set to UTF-8

That seems to work for me.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to test it out but that looks to be everything I need.

Comment: I have done the following adding the header to the top of the php file header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');. I have then proceeded to set up the meta tag as <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> and I checked my database collation which is set to utf8_general_ci. It is still showing the japanese characters as ?. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

You have to deliver the documents with the proper encoding declaration in the [HTTP header field `Content-Type`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17).

In PHP you do this via the [`header` function](http://docs.php.net/header) before the first data has been send to the client, so preferably as one of the first statements:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');

    // the rest
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you were right, I firebugged it and that's exactly the problem.  Love this site.

Comment: Unhappily we still live in an ISO 8859-1 world …

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'll assume the same client machine is used for both tests.

So, use Firebug or your tool-of-choice to check the HTTP response headers on your local server, and compare them with the headers generated by the other servers. You will no doubt find a difference.

Typically your server should be including a header like this in the response:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

If the headers on the two systems look pretty much the same, grab the body of both responses and load it up in a hex editor and look for encoding differences.

Answer (score 0):

**Try following (worked for me, CentOS 6.8, PHP 5.6)**

**#1**
    Apache Config

> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
>   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

**#2**
    PHP Config

> /etc/php.ini:
>   default_charset = "utf-8" >> default_charset = "Shift_JIS"

**Note : set error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT**

**#3**
    html head meta

> http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS"