# PHP and UTF-8 (and Windows as well)

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

Here is the situation:

I'm using UTF-8 to input Japanese characters into a MySQL database, using a php form. However while done from my PC it works perfectly and the script records the characters correctly into the DB, **but** from other PCs the script inputs raw symbols. I've declared completely all the things regarding the UTF-8 header, meta tag, etc. I'm sure this is not a php/sql issue, (because it works perfectly from one pc) but something from windows configuration I cannot understand.

Anyone knows something regarding this issue?

Comment: look this link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666987/how-to-display-japanese-characters-on-a-php-page` may be it will help!

Comment: I have already a collection for any possible fixes for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083847/accented-characters-in-utf-8-mysql-table-output

Comment: I assume you have done this: `mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");` ?